# Rate of change for : b= -0.9t + 100 and b= -5t + 100

Tags: linear-algebra

I’ve looked through all of my notes and scoured what seems like the whole internet but I cannot for the life of me understand how to do rate of change for an equation like this, i thought it was y1 y2/ x1 x2 or something like that, please help a desperate student out!

Here’s the info for the question :
According to Capital Journal of Health, if a human loses more than 60% body mass due to starvation or dehydration, it is unlikely he/she will survive. In order for Katniss and Peeta to win the Hunger Games, they must overcome the challenges they face with limited access to food and water.
Let b represent the % body mass remaining and t represent the number of days since the Hunger Games began.

Hunger equation : b = -0.9t + 100

Dehydration equation : -5t + 100

The following chart was provided to all tributes before entering the Hunger Games to ensure that they are able to identify when their health is at high risk.

[here’s the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmPu3.jpg)

You are entrusted with monitoring the health of the tributes during the hunger games. Your job is to explain to the game maker who's health is in immediate danger due to dehydration and hunger. Your assignment to the Capitol requires you to answer a series of questions.

Q1 : 1 Feutarch wants to know the rate ofchange for each equation, and what it represents for the tributes and their health.

Q2 : President Snow would like to understand what the v intercept for each equation represents.

Update : IM SORRY I DONT UNDERSTAND Q3 ETHIER

[image: **here’s the question **]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Instead of trying to remember formulas, start by thinking about what the equation $b=-0.9t+100$ does. What's the value of $b$ when $t=0$? When $t=1$? When $t=20$? What do these values mean in terms of the dehydration situation? Can you picture the graph of $b$ vs. $t$?

Comment: Have you tried a drawing, with colors that denote the various ranges? You have two variables.